# ON_BN_CLICKED Call Non-Member Function

Tags: c++, button, mfc, click, pointer-to-member

The `ON_BN_CLICKED` macro takes a button ID and a member function pointer. When the button is clicked the member function is called.

I have a member function, `foo`, who's pointer I have passed to `ON_BN_CLICKED`:

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(1485, &foo)
```

But `foo` just directly calls outside the class to my business logic function:

```
void presentation::foo() {
    business->foo();
}
```

I want to setup `ON_BN_CLICKED` to directly call this business logic function. Is this possible?

Comment: Posting the code you are trying would help understand your question.

Comment: @rrirower I've added code, but to me it makes the question more convoluted. What do you think?

Comment: Having to make your business logic aware of UI implementation details is never not a mistake.  If you don't like the consequences of layering then just don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Wait, what are you saying here? My UI does keep a pointer to the business logic back end. Are you suggesting that's a mistake?

Comment: UI dependent upon Business Logic - good.  Business Logic dependent upon UI - bad.  If you understand MFC's Document/View architecture, you can understand that a Document (Business Logic) can be tied to multi views (even different types of views).  CDialogs don't follow MFC's CDocument/CView specifically, but you can "model" it through your own "Business Logic" classes, like you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, but I'd discourage it.  If you're thinking performance gain, the compiler may optimize out the extra call anyway.  If you decompose the `ON_BN_CLICKED` macro, you'd see it ends up being an array entry in an array in `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`...`END_MESSAGE_MAP` which has `CCmdTarget` function pointers in it.  So, if your `business` class was derived from `CCmdTarget` you could avoid some casting problems and call it directly.  An easier approach might be to have your own `WM_COMMAND` processing and/or not rely on the message map mechanism and do your own window procedure.  But again this is a lot of work for little or no gain.

Comment: The call is triggerd by the UI, so the little extra performance gain won't change anything anyway.